# Set an image with a static name but with a variety of extensions

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, vuejs2

I am building an application where the user can make use of a setup wizard. In there you can select an image for the shoplogo, but I want to give the person the freedom to choose between multiple extensions (ofcourse some limitations but you get the idea).

Currently I can store the image by a given name and it does the job, but the way I retrieve the image right now is by making an API call to the backend to retrieve the name plus extension. I feel like this takes up too much time to load in, instead I would like to retrieve the image immediately from the folder. In this folder there will always be one file located, but the app needs to know what the file type is in order to display the image.

The current implementation:

```
<img v-if="shopInfo" class="navbar-brand mx-auto d-block w-50" :src="'/shop/' + shopInfo.image"/>
```

How do I do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What if you just want to know the type of file.
You can set `type` attr with your `select` or `input` tag.

On these tag, you can add `type="image/jpeg"` or `type="application/pdf"` to limitate user's uploaded file type.

For display image or pdf, you can use `<embed>` tag to achieve, here is an example:

```
<embed
     v-if="embedSrc"
     type="video/webm"
     :src="embedSrc"
     width="100%"
     style="max-height: 50rem; min-height: 20rem"
/>
...

data:{
  return{
     embedSrc: ''
   }
}

...
```

Not sure this solution can help you to solve the issue frankly, if it not to suitable to you, maybe you can leave more detail for your question.